# How to Retrieve Only Words that Begin with Vowel

Tags: python, python-re

I have two strings:

```
text_one = '"A Ukrainian American woman who lives near Boston, Massachusetts, told Fox News Digital on Monday that she can no longer speak on the phone with her own mother, who lives in southern Ukraine, because of the Russian attacks on Ukraine and the fear these attacks have engendered.'
text_two = '\n\nMany people in southern Ukraine — as well as throughout the country — are right now living in fear for their lives as Russian soldiers overtake the area, the Boston-area woman said."'
```

I need to retrieve only the words that start with a vowel, for example:

> A Ukranian American on on own Ukraine... etc.

From a previous question I had asked, I've been messing around with `import re`, but do not have a strong grasp on it yet. My idea is to find any instance of a consonant *after* a [ ] character and sub all characters up until the next [ ] with []. So far I have:

```
#import re library
import re

#establish strings, formatted for visual clarity
text_one = '"A Ukrainian American woman who lives near Boston, Massachusetts, told Fox News Digital on Monday that she can no longer speak on the phone with her own mother, who lives in southern Ukraine, because of the Russian attacks on Ukraine and the fear these attacks have engendered.'
text_two = '\n\nMany people in southern Ukraine — as well as throughout the country — are right now living in fear for their lives as Russian soldiers overtake the area, the Boston-area woman said."'

#define function to replace words that begin with a consonant
def replace(cons):
  return re.sub(r ##some kind of method to grab characters after [ ], beginning with consonant, ending at character before next [ ]##), ##some kind of lambda argument to sub characters for [] (nothing)##...
```

Comment: You could use `\b` that represents word boundry, exhaustively list all possible vowels e.g. `[aeiouAEIOU]`, then accept anything until the next word boundry.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text_one = '"A Ukrainian American woman who lives near Boston, Massachusetts, told Fox News Digital on Monday that she can no longer speak on the phone with her own mother, who lives in southern Ukraine, because of the Russian attacks on Ukraine and the fear these attacks have engendered.'
list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.findall("\W[aieou][^ ]*", text_one, flags=re.I | re.M)))
```